# Database Design for one-on-one sports

Tags: database-design

Let's say that I'm developing an application to track boxing results. Is the best way to track these to have two tables, like so:

```
Boxers
======
id
name

Matches
=======
id
match_number
boxer_id
opponent_id
result
```

... and then have two records for each match, one for the winner, and one for the loser, something like this:

```
id match_number boxer_id opponent_id result
-- ------------ -------- ----------- ------
1  1            1001     2001        WIN
2  1            2001     1001        LOSS
```

... or am I missing a better way to do this?

What if there wasn't a result stored, just a recording that the two opponents were matched up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a fully normalized, I'd go with:

Boxers - as cited.

Matches:

```
id  / match_number   (Don't think these need to be distinct anymore)
winner (FK-Boxers; Nullable, for for matches scheduled, but not decided yet)
```

Opponents:

```
id  (meaningless PK value.  Optional. 
     you could use the other two fields as the PK)
match_id
boxer_id
```

Two rows in Opponents and one in Matches for each match.

(Updated to add suggestions from other answers)

Comment: this approach has the advantage of allowing you to easily query for all the matches which someone is in, instead of having to query for all the matches where they are a boxer, and all the matches they are an opponent.

Comment: I realize this is ancient but I'm trying to do a similar thing for UFC fights. I'm curious how you would query all matches which a fighter was in since they may not be the winner. I scraped a bunch of UFC data and have Fight_ID, F1_ID, F2_ID, F1_is_winner, F1_is_winner in the fight table but this is not working for me. Trying to wrap my head around proper table design.

Answer (score 2):

Store the `winner_id` in the same record.
This allows you to show upcoming fights, unlike solutions that suggest storing `winner_id` and `loser_id` only as no winner or loser exists before a fight takes place.

#### Matches

- match_id
- match_date
- winner_id

#### Match Fighters

- match_id
- fighter_id

#### Fighters

- fighter_id
- fighter_name

Answer (score 0):

Storing the winner ID would cut the number of records in the Matches table in half. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to store the opponent ID.

Answer (score 0):

Boxers as in the question

Matches with:

```
match_id int pk
winner_id int fk
loser_id int fk
result(_id) int/bool nullable
date
...
```

If the result can only be "win" or "unknown", a nullable boolean is sufficient.

If there are different result types (e.g. the name of the technique that led to the win/loss in sumo), use a nullable int.

When you store data, you should always ask yourself: what kind of questions should my data be able to answer.

Comment: This is currently how I have a similar table setup for a UFC database but am stuck on how to properly query out what fights a fighter has been in. Rather than Winner_ID and Loser_ID I just have F1_Id, F2_id. When querying out any fights where either F1 or F2 is a certain fighter ID and also including their name I only get the name of F1 since both of them are foreign keys to the Fighter_ID. Any tips on how to properly do this?